# Using Titanium I want to loop through an array 1 by 1 after clicking the next button and backwards using the previous button

Tags: javascript, loops

//Using Titanium I want to loop through an array 1 by 1 after clicking the next button and backwards //using the previous button but everytime I do it it loops through the entire array... here is what I //have so far:

```
var fishArray = ["tang", "clownfish", "rabbit fish", "trigger fish", "blue green chromis", "angelfish"];
var index = 0;

var forwards = function(){

for(var i = index, j=fishArray.length; i<j; index++){
    var fishLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text: fishArray[index],
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        width: 250,
        height: 200,
        top: view1.height + spacing,
        borderRadius: 5,
        borderWidth: 1
    });
    win1.add(fishLabel);
}
};


button1.addEventListener("click", backwards);
button2.addEventListener("click", forwards);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe `index++` is missing, you have to increment/decrement it

and the loop looks strange

try this

```
for(var i = index; i<fishArray.length; i++)
```

and change

```
text: fishArray[index],
```

to

```
text: fishArray[i],
```

whole code:

```
var fishArray = ["tang", "clownfish", "rabbit fish", "trigger fish", "blue green chromis", "angelfish"];
var index = 0;

var labels = function(){
    for(var i = index; i<fishArray.length; i++){
        var fishLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
            text: fishArray[i],
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
            width: 250,
            height: 200,
            top: view1.height + spacing,
            borderRadius: 5,
            borderWidth: 1
        });
        win1.add(fishLabel);
    }
};
var backwards = function(){
    labels();
    index--;
};
var forwards = function(){
    labels();
    index++;
};


button1.addEventListener("click", backwards);
button2.addEventListener("click", forwards);
```